# App stops inconsistently at a call to dispatch_sync()

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, xmppframework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App blocks while dipatching a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315645/app-blocks-while-dipatching-a-queue)

I'm using XMPPFramework, and in its code there's a method like this:

```
- (NSDictionary *)occupants
{
    if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == moduleQueue)
    {
        return occupants;
    }
    else
    {
        __block NSDictionary *result;

        dispatch_sync(moduleQueue, ^{//IT BLOCKS HERE
            result = [occupants copy];
        });

        return [result autorelease];
    }
}
```

It gets stuck there inconsistently, not always; the app is not responding, but it's not crashing, so I pause it and I see the thread (Thread 1) has stopped there. If I press play, nothing changes. What is wrong? Any ideas?