# UI is not updating when loading Data

Tags: swift

During a loading-process I'm trying to update my UI (a label and a progress bar) from within a loop.

The UI is not updating though, until the loading-function is done.

The loading-function is not using another thread, I'm still in the main thread so from my understanding it should be possible to instantly-update the UI...

Is there something I am missing?

loading-function: (called from viewDidAppear)

```
    func LoadDataFromDataCore(){

    //1
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "CDGlobeTile")

    //3
    do {
        let DataCoreResult = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        var LabelFromCDArray = [LabelTile]()

        for (index, CDGlobeTile) in DataCoreResult.enumerated() {

            updateLoadingBar(Progress: Float(index) / Float(DataCoreResult.count - 1))

        // "unpack" the data from CoreData...

        } 



        do{
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error saving context. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }



    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    print(" finished loading")

}
```

updateLoadingBar - function:

```
func updateLoadingBar(Progress: Float){

    let percentage = Progress * 100


    if let currentDispatch = OperationQueue.current?.underlyingQueue {
        print(currentDispatch)
        // this gives me "<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread>" 
    }



    LoadingLabel.text = String(format: "%2.0f", percentage)
    ProgressBar.progress = Progress


}
```

Comment: please post some code

Comment: are you using
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* code */ }) ` for updating UI elements?

Comment: yeah, I tried to call it explicitly from inside the main_queue but it's not changing anything. In fact I recognized that print()-statements that I place there are only called after the loading-function is done.

Comment: check your loading function first. Or place it here so we could help.

Comment: btw check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17920357/1040347

Comment: Okay, I posted the code of the loading-function.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov hmm I see, so am I supposed to do the loading and unpacking in a secondary thread and the UI-updating in the main-thread?  I can do that, but I just don't understand why it's not working when I do everything inside the main-thread...

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the updateProgressBar function and confirming you are definitely getting results and entering the loop

Comment: @LostReminder yes, heavy-duty tasks like fetching/writing data, downloading from the internet should be performed on the background thread.

Comment: @Scriptable I am entering the loop, I was using print statements to make sure of that. The data is loaded properly

Comment: Instead of ProgressBar.progress try, progressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true). Also, try calling "updateLoadingBar" on the main que. "DispatchQueue.main.async { updateLoadingBar(...... "