# Understanding dispatch_sync routine

Tags: ios

Im learning GCD. Please consider following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Hello world");
    });

   /* Another implementation */
   return YES;
}
```

I know, that there will be a deadlock. But can somebody explain why? What exactly steps application will do, before it (app) will "freeze"?

Comment: Why do you assert there will be a deadlock?

Comment: @trojanfoe because app will freeze. Please try it.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar its not swift

Comment: Won't it depend what queue that code is called from?

Comment: @trojanfoe ok, my bad, i will edit question body.

Comment: This question has already been answered here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379059/why-is-this-dispatch-sync-call-freezing>

Answer (score 1):

because the code runs in main queue and you tell it to wait for the block to execute in main queue